# How to include only one column for searching from gridview using Javascript in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, gridview

I got a function from google for client side searching from grid using `textbox`

and the function is :

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function filter2(phrase, _id) {
            var words = phrase.value.toLowerCase().split(" ");
            var table = document.getElementById(_id);
            var ele;
            for (var r = 1; r < table.rows.length; r++) {
                ele = table.rows[r].innerHTML.replace(/<[^>]+>/g, "");
                var displayStyle = 'none';
                for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
                    if (ele.toLowerCase().indexOf(words[i]) >= 0)
                        displayStyle = '';
                    else {
                        displayStyle = 'none';
                        break;
                    }
                }
                table.rows[r].style.display = displayStyle;
            }
        }

    </script>
```

and calling from `textbox` is as:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" TabIndex="2"  onkeyup="filter2(this, '<%=GridView1.ClientID %>');" runat="server"  AutoPostBack="True"/>
```

and the `Gridview` I used for searching is as:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1"  runat="server"  AutoGenerateColumns="False"    >
                                            <Columns>
<asp:BoundField DataField="ClassName" HeaderText="Class Name" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="PerWeekClass" HeaderText="Week Classes" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="SubID" visible="false" />
                                            </Columns>
                                           </asp:GridView>
```

the issue I got is this function searches string from all the columns of  the grid but,

I need only first column that should function search string from.

I am weak in java script so I need your help to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: One question.... Must use javascript to filter ?

Comment: it is client side and i got order from higher command to do like this,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code where you can try...

.aspx

```
    <asp:TextBox ID="txt" runat="server" onkeyup="filter(this);"></asp:TextBox>

    <br />

    <asp:GridView ID="gv" runat="server" Width="100%" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Filter" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" />
        </Columns>

    </asp:GridView>
```

Javascript

```
function filter(txt) {
        var grid = document.getElementById("<%=gv.ClientID %>");
        var row = grid.rows.length;
        var filterValue = txt.value.toLowerCase();
        var splitter = filterValue.split(' ');
        var display = '';
        var currentRowValue = '';

        for (var i = 1; i < row; i++) {
            display = 'none';
            currentRowValue = grid.rows[i].cells[0].innerText;

            for (var j = 0; j < splitter.length; j++) {
                if (currentRowValue.toLowerCase().startsWith(splitter[j]))
                    display = '';
                else {
                    display = 'none';
                    break;
                }
            }
            grid.rows[i].style.display = display;
        }
    }
```

Code Behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Check
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        // Varaible
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Filter");
        dt.Columns.Add("Name");

        // Add
        dt.Rows.Add("Do", "Doraemon");
        dt.Rows.Add("No", "Nobita");
        dt.Rows.Add("Si", "Sizuka");
        dt.Rows.Add("Sin", "Sinyu");

        // Bind
        gv.DataSource = dt;
        gv.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: this works fine. thanks for your time. i need 1 thing more that this function checks string containing sequence so if i need to  search string from start of sequence just like "Like" query in SQL.. so what to do ? i thinks you understood..?

Comment: @Waqas Change the javascript "indexOf" to "match".. then remove the condition ">= 0" Read this... http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/string_match.htm

Comment: @Waqas updated the code. If this is the answer for you please check it as answered :)

Comment: Do you get any error in javascript ? for not working ? I tried in my end is working

Comment: no i didn't get any error. but when i typed string in textbox it did nothing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89556/discussion-between-nicholas-and-waqas).

Comment: I used updated , again it works on contain sequence along with start with string both... but i need only start with..

Comment: Oh i misunderstand your request i thought you want something like SQL "%LIKE%". You mean you want First character is "S" then search "S"

Comment: sorry for my incomplete description., i need this 's%' if string is "Some thing" and on typing "s" it should retrieve all strings starting with "s"...

Comment: now working like a charm. thanks bro.. it is very helpful. i appreciate. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
ele = table.rows[r].innerHTML.replace(/<[^>]+>/g, "");
```

To

```
ele = table.rows[r].cells[0].innerHTML.replace(/<[^>]+>/g, "");
```